# Multiple Domains With SSL CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have a web app application on `app.mywebapp.com`
I want users of this app to be able to have a custom domain name

For example `docs.theirsite.com`

I'm hosting via CloudFront. I have it working but I face 2 issues.

The first is that there is a limit of 100 alternative cnames per cloud distribution. This is not a problem at the moment but hopefully it will be in the future.

The second is that CloudFront only supports one ssl/tls cert per distribution. To provide ssl/tls for multiple domains I need to request a new cert from Certificate Manager with the new domain I want to add. Then update the CloudFront Distribution with this new cert.

I feel like this is not the best way to solve this problem. I would love some advice. Thank you.

Comment: how did you end up solving this? running into the same issue

Answer (score 3):

The limit on web distributions is now 200 per account,  but this is a soft limit that can be increased on request, see [General Limits on Web Distributions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-web-distributions) in the CloudFront Developer Guide.

The limit on alternate domain names can also be increased on request, but it's unlikely that this is the right path -- you won't be able to get a certificate with this many unique hostnames that will actually be usable.

Unless all of your sites are serving the same static content for each domain, there's little point in trying to consolidate them into monolithic multi-domain distributions.

The limit of a single certificate per distribution is not something that can be changed.

Comment: Thank you for the information on CloudFront. All of the sites are serving the same content. It's a VueJs app.